# Adding inheritance in C++ multiple class file

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I am learning C++ from the book called "Beginning C++ through Game Programming" and this problem showed up. The following code was originally 1 file, but I had to divide it into multiple classes.

Now, I am stuck at **inheritance** problem. I watched videos, read tutorials about it but nothing seemed to help. The book doesn't help either. I need to add the following attributes:

- Use the multiple file class version (I am using it)
- From a critter base class -- add at least 2 inheritance critters
- The base class should have at least 2 attributes (data)
- The inherited class should have at least 2 additional traits different from the base class and the other inherited class
- Add the appropriate functions for all the attributes -- both base and inherited
- Add appropriate menu items

Any help here would be highly appreciated!

critter.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Critter
{
public:
    Critter(const string& name = "");
    string GetName() const;  

private:
    string m_Name;
};
```

critterImp.cpp

```
#include <critter.h>
Critter::Critter(const string& name):
    m_Name(name)
{}

inline string Critter::GetName() const 
{
    return m_Name;
}
```

farm.h

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Critter;

class Farm
{
public:
    Farm(int spaces = 1); 
    void Add(const Critter& aCritter);
    void RollCall() const;

private:
    vector<Critter> m_Critters;
};
```

farmImp.cpp

```
#include <farm.h>
#include <critter.h>

Farm::Farm(int spaces)
{
    m_Critters.reserve(spaces);
}

void Farm::Add(const Critter& aCritter)
{
    m_Critters.push_back(aCritter);
}

void Farm::RollCall() const
{
    for (vector<Critter>::const_iterator iter = m_Critters.begin(); 
         iter != m_Critters.end(); 
         ++iter)
    {
        cout << iter->GetName() << " here.\n";
    }
}
```

critFarmTest.cpp

```
#include <farm.h>
#include <critter.h>

int main()
{
    Critter crit("Poochie");
    cout << "My critter's name is " << crit.GetName() << endl; 

    cout << "\nCreating critter farm.\n";
    Farm myFarm(3);

    cout << "\nAdding three critters to the farm.\n";
    myFarm.Add(Critter("Moe"));
    myFarm.Add(Critter("Larry"));
    myFarm.Add(Critter("Curly"));

    cout << "\nCalling Roll...\n";
    myFarm.RollCall();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem/error message?

Comment: You may like to remove `inline` in `inline string Critter::GetName() const`, otherwise it may not link.